# How can I make my logo look crisp on the web?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, logo

I'm launching a company and my logo looks really pixelated and low-quality compared to some others. For example, http://talentegg.ca/ has a really crisp logo, how can I get mine like this?

Mine, which is better? Both of which can be improved though

1. [image: 1]
2. [image: 2]
3. Illustrator version - [image: scaled]
4. saved for web version - [image: web]

Please help!! I have Adobe Photoshop CS6

Comment: sometimes i combine the logo with the text - by mask -

Comment: Cheers, @GM3 - What do you mean by that?

Comment: Do you have Illustrator too? That would be a much better tool to use for a logo like that: you'd have it as vector graphics, for much easier use in various other applications. Is your logo this pixellated in Photoshop as well? That could indicate that you've set your anti-aliasing too soft.

Comment: Cheers, @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I have adobe illustrator. I can try remaking it there? What do I render it as?

Comment: That's what I would do, yes. The little vortex icon should be relatively easy to draw as a vector shape in Illustrator, and the text is of course just text.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Super helpful! I've nearly got it, I'm making the vortex however, I'm having trouble erasing the openings of the circles to make it a vortex. When using the Eraser tool, when I erase a section it is just bends the shape, and doesn't erase it?

Comment: Nvm got it. Had to use eraser then select tool to delete area

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Hey, I've remade the logo and updated the post. However, when I add it to photoshop it looks pixelated too. How should I export it from Illustrator so that it looks crisp?

Comment: Just use Illustrator’s _Save for web_ feature, which is fairly similar to Photoshop’s—no reason to use Photoshop at all here. And to get the logo in a flexible format that you can use in Word documents and such things, just _Save as_ a PDF file. (Use the Artboard tool to crop the document to just the logo before doing both, of course.)

Comment: Done, ty :) it looks similar though still a bit pixelated? Or maybe it's just me. Re-did the entire logo, even used maths for the vortex. Let me know your thoughts if there's anything else I can do. May be fine now.

Comment: It is often better to leave the resizing to the browser—they do a better job of matching subpixel hinting geared at the actual OS and rendering on the viewer’s machine than a one-time rendering based solely on your machine. In other words, do like TalentEgg have done and export a much larger version of your logo, and then specify in the CSS of your page what size it should be. TalentEgg’s logo is actually [500 px wide](http://talentegg.ca/images/logo.png), even though on the page it’s scaled to 128 px in width.

Answer (score 1):

http://talentegg.ca/images/logo.png -> ( Logo image for the example link have 500*133 px size in actual but in header it is of only 128px width. )

As you can see in this example they have used big size image and give custom width using CSS. You can use you Illustrator file.. make it of approx 600px width while saving as png file. Then there is no need to use Photoshop. Finally when you add to website make it of width 200px or 100px as your need. Hope you got my point and is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have your original logo in multiple formats including .eps or .ai?
For maximum crispiness on the web, you could export from those formats to an .svg format which is a vector format for the web medium.

The anti-aliasing shows more on your logo than on Talentegg.ca, probably simply because it uses black which contrasts more on white.

On another note, if I had designed your logo, I would be pleased to supply you with an appropriate format so I would just contact the original graphic designer if I were you. Retracing the logo yourself is just not a good idea result-wise and ethics-wise.

Comment: Thanks @Emilie, I made the original but in photoshop and lost the file :(. SVG looks much better, however the font changes. Is it possible to keep the same font and save as .svg?

Comment: Select your font and "Create Outlines" to turn it into shapes, you should be good after that!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the image is larger http://talentegg.ca/images/logo.png than it appears on screen. That's the trick. Add a large image and then scale it down in css. Also once you export your large png for web you can compress it even further using https://tinypng.com/.

I used that on the logos on my site http://galnova.com

I hope this helps.