# I'm re-making a logo, how do I make a vortex in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, website-design, logo

Here's the original (made in photoshop), but it's way too pixelated so I'm re making it in illustrator.

[image: v]

However, I'm having a very difficult time re-making the vortex. I've tried using the Ellipse tool and stack circles and then cutting them but it's not working at all. The circles look all weird and distorted. Any help here would be great!

Answer (score 3):

This is something that would be easy to graph with a [parametric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation). You can find a parametric equation plotter I made for illustrator here:

- [jooGraphFunction.jsx](https://bitbucket.org/joojaa/jooillustratorscripts/src/06a32f7d5ea0f75b6a8f142bafe989096e13ed3e/jooGraphFunction.jsx?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

I quickly tested with following parameters:

```
Function:
X: 2.2*(t+3*PI) * sin(t) + 300
Y: 1*(t+3*PI)* cos(t) - 200 + 6/4*PI*t

Range:
Min: 3*PI/4+0.5
Max: PI*6+2*PI/4
Step: PI/8 (or PI/4)
```

[image: Result]

**Image 1**: Graphing of a suitable parametric equation yields.

You may want to adjust the numeric values of the equation a bit to suit your needs. This is quickly done after all.

For finishing touches. Use the cut tool to cut the shape up and delete segments at overlapping joins.

[image: After twaking]

**Image 2**: After twaking a bit more Result after making raise a bit bigger (the term 6/4*PI*t).

Comment: +1 just for including lots of number and symbol gibberish and actually make something sensible out of them. (Though my instinctive reaction to so much maths all at once is to head for the hills. **Edit:** Oh god. I just clicked the Wikipedia link. Someone please help me mop up the remains of my now-exploded brain.)

Comment: Wow, that's awesome, thanks! - albeit, I'm having trouble implementing the code into the Illustrator source code. Can you make the vortex thicker to match the logo width and I can just use your clearer vortex!

Comment: @Apane101 Copy the code and place it in text file and drop the file on top of illustrator. Once you've made the vortex shape you can edit its thickness to whatever you want. Its just a path, and stroke weight will govern the thickness of shape lines.

Comment: @joojaa Wow that was easy, so I've got the GraphFunction loaded, and I've entered in the params, however when I click ok, I don't see anything. What tool do I need to select to display the vortex?

Comment: You need to have a document open. Make sure you actually have some color to your brush. Hit ctl + a to select everything and then select view fit all in window (in case your artboard is not near 0)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet well you probably liked [this questions answers](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54014/is-math-needed-for-graphic-design/). If that's the case.

Comment: @joojaa I need to make the middle loop a bit smaller, see comparison here from new and original - http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60832/how-can-i-make-my-logo-look-crisp-on-the-web/60848#60848 which fields need to be tweaked? Thanks!